# Manually change state with ui-router in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a search bar in my app. Anytime a user makes a search, I'd like the state to change to `/#/search/:query`

To do so, I attach the following function to the scope and I trigger it anytime a query is made:

```
this.searchItem = function searchItem(item) {
  $state.go('#/search/' + item)
}
```

However this results in the following error:

```
Error: Couldn't resolve '#/search/query' from state (current state) at object.transition.To
```

What is the problem with my code? How can I change state without using anchors with ui-router?

Many thanks

Comment: As [@natwallbank](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2841771/natwallbank) pointed out, you need to pass the *name of the state* to the `go` function: `$state.go("search", { "query": item });`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a URL when you need to pass the name of your state.  See the [ui-router wiki](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) for examples.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to post this as a comment and suggest the question be refined?

Comment: I thought I answered the question, unless I misunderstood it.  He's trying to transition to a different state within a controller (probably) rather than using ui-sref in a view.  The reason it wasn't working is that he was passing a URL rather than the name of the state that he needs to transition to.

Comment: How is "you're doing it wrong" going to help future answer-seekers? Either the question is "Off Topic" and should be corrected, or your answer is not specific enough to be helpful. Does that make sense? The intent of the site isn't for the benefit of the asker, but for the understanding of everyone trying to accomplish similar tasks.

Comment: I don't understand @Shmiddty's problems with the answer.  "You're doing it wrong" is the reason the OP had a question in the first place.  natwallbank said, "you need to pass the name of the state" and since the OP didn't post his state configuration, that's the most he could elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the name of the state instead of the url.

```
this.searchItem = function searchItem(item) {
  $state.go('search', {
    keyword: item
  });
}
```

Assuming you have this state configuration in your routes.

```
$stateProvider.state('search', {
  url: '/search/:keyword'
})
```

You can check my sample repo here: [here](https://github.com/kevinfelisilda/my-app/blob/master/src/modules/route.js) and [here](https://github.com/kevinfelisilda/my-app/blob/master/src/modules/nav/nav-controller.js#L27)